# layout is different in real device

Tags: android, layout

I'm developing android app that have few activities. I have Samsung S6 device in my hand, so I created the same device in the android studio emulator to make it easy. But the problem is when I install the APK in my physical device it's not showing the layout as the emulator device. I used the same screen size ( 5.1 ) & the same resolution of 1440 pixels by 2560 pixels when creating the emulator device. can someone please help me ?

I also uploaded 2 screen shots to better understanding.

[In Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igSWI.png)

[In Real Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njJgj.png)

Comment: That is because it defers in dpi.. The dpi of the phone is more than that of the emulator, hence the UI looks different.

Comment: so If I'm using dp other than sp will this resolve the problem ? can I define the dpi for emulator device ?

Comment: While creating new Emulator, see the right most column called `Density` and choose the same density as your phone. Changing dp to sp might solve the issue, I've not tried though. Please try it to find out.